# Interesting behaviour of contextlib.redirect_stdout

Tags: python

Let's start with a contrived piece of code. Explanation will follow:

```
from timeit import timeit
from os import devnull
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

def process():
    for i in range(1_000):
        print(f"Message {i}")

N = 10_000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with redirect_stdout(None):
        t = timeit(process, number=N)
    print(t)
    with open(devnull, "a") as _null:
        with redirect_stdout(_null):
            t = timeit(process, number=N)
    print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
1.0380362079886254
2.2988220420083962
```

So, as you can see, there's a significant difference in the timings. This is due to passing None to redirect_stdout() rather than a valid file-type object.

The documentation for redirect_stdout() says nothing about this "trick" - I just stumbled across it whilst researching something else. Under the covers, what happens is that None is assigned to sys.stdout.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there documentation anywhere that explains this (very useful) behaviour? - i.e., when sys.stdout is assigned None, stdout output is suppressed.
2. Is it likely to be future-proof?

**Platform:**

```
macOS 14.3 on M2
Python 3.12.1
```

Comment: @KamilCuk What I'm querying is the behaviour of sys.stdout being assigned None

Answer (score 2):

> when sys.stdout is assigned None, stdout output is suppressed.

Not exactly. `print()` ends up doing nothing, but this will break anything relying on `sys.stdout` being a writable file-like, so I would advise against this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
...   sys.stdout.write("hello")  # imagine this to be in a library if you will
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

*`print()`* in particular *doesn't* break because of [this segment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17689e3c41d9f61bcd1928b24d3c50c37ceaf3f2/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2046-L2049) in `bltinmodule.c`:

```
       /* sys.stdout may be None when FILE* stdout isn't connected */
        if (file == Py_None) {
            Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }
```

This was introduced in 2007 in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/fef9bbaff2513f1b17f5aa2b9a44e3d32855f082) to fix [BPO-1415 (GH#45756)](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/45756), so I suspect that behavior isn't going anywhere soon.